# Parse ecommerce product data via PHP

Tags: php, laravel, curl, html-parsing

Given a webpage for example:

- [https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-High-Speed-HDMI-Cable-Standard/dp/B014I8SSD0/ref=pd_bxgy_23_img_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=Y5T0HTXEAC6TVNH5H15Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014I8SSD0)
- http://www.dodocase.com/products/lorna-iphone-wallet-case

Is there a way for me to get the product name and price of the product via PHP? Is there a PHP library or package I can use for this?

P.S. I'm using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. It is called crawling/parsing. I would recommend [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library, since laravel has a composer you can easily implement it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend https://github.com/dweidner/laravel-goutte
It is a Facade for the Goutte client : https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

Answer (score 0):

You can parse commerce product data useing "HTML Data Scrapping" for this you can use "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" Library (i.e. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

You can read more details of this library. How to use this library from this blog (i.e. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library--net-11856)